# Trying to build horizontal scrollable ListView

Tags: flutter, listview

I want to build a horizontal scrollable ListView with 2 containers on top of each other. The idea is to build something like this:

[image: Expected]

My idea for this is to be a SizedBox with ListView builder child. However, I cannot find how to stack those 2 containers on the top of each other. Should I be using Stack widget or something else? A guidance here would be very appreciated.

This is where I'm so far:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: deviceWidth * 0.55,
  child: ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: 15,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
        child: Stack(
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      children: [
        Container(color: whitePrimary),
        Container(
          color: Colors.purple,
        )
      ],
    )),
  ),
),
```

Where my goal was to display 2 containers on top of each other, just to test out the Stack Widget, but without success..

In the code above, the deviceHeight property is:

```
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

double deviceHeight = size.height;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 4,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Stack(children: [
                Container(
                  height: 150,
                  width: 120,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 120,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            offset: Offset(0, 5),
                            blurRadius: 10)
                      ]),
                )
              ]);
            },
          ),
        )
```

Comment: it does build me the purple container only, I cannot see it on top of the white one as it is in the picture in my question.

Comment: can you share image of it and bottom container color is also white keep it in mind ok

Comment: yeah, something was wrong with compiling. Everything works as fine. This is exactly what I've been looking for, after resizing the containers with desired height and width. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the `Container` with [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) to align it in the `Stack`. You also need to give the `Container` actual child widget so it starts appearing on the screen.

```
Stack(
  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
  children: [
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Text('This is a sentence'),
    ),
    Align( // Align the second Container to the top center of the Stack
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.purple,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30),
          child: Text('This is on the top container'),
        ),
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Another option is to use the [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget.

Comment: So in order to do as it is in the picture, I need to make the size of the white colored container larger that the purple one?

Comment: Yes, so that the `Stack` will size to the `Container`'s size. Or you can make 3 widgets in the `Stack`: the first one is a `SizedBox` (to give the `Stack` the desired size), second one is `Container` that's aligned to the bottom, third one is the `Container` that's aligned to the top